# Firebase clouds, stripe and ios

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, stripe-payments, google-cloud-functions

Do anybody have a good example or source code for integrating firebase clouds, stripe on ios using swift?

This is an sample code that I got from: [Stripe firebase example code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe)

```
    'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions'),
      admin = require('firebase-admin'),
      logging = require('@google-cloud/logging')();

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.token),
      currency = functions.config().stripe.currency || 'USD';
```

But how do I connect it the backend to my ios app?

Comment: Check out my answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239322/swift-firebase-stripe-connect/48239411#48239411

Answer (score 0):

Your app should trigger the execution of the cloud function. Check [this tutorial](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/collect-payments-with-angular-stripe-checkout-and-firebase/). The functionality will be independent of *your backend ios app* as it should be triggered from ios/Android/web... all potential clients.